# how to use history.push() in React-router-dom version 6.0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

add the history in top of the code like `import {history} form react-router-dom

```
history.push({
   pathname:"/users",
   state:{
   Key : response.data.user }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See [the upgrade guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory) in the documentation.

> Use useNavigate instead of useHistory

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
const someFunction = () => {
     const options = {
         state: { 
             Key: response.data.use
         }
     }
     navigate("/users", options);
}
```